# CNAME redirection not working in GoDaddy

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I have a domain name `myapp.com` with GoDaddy, and I've deployed the site to Azure, so now the app is in `myapp.cloudapp.net`.

I'm trying to set up a `CNAME` from `www.myapp.com` to `myapp.cloudapp.net` but it doesn't work after two days and I was wondering if I've done something wrong.

I've set up a `CNAME` record from `www` to `myapp.cloudapp.net` in my DNS Manager in GoDaddy, and a forwarding from `myapp.com` to `www.myapp.com`. I did this on Friday.

When I try to access `myapp.com` I get redirected to `www.myapp.com`, but then it says "Page not found", actually if I do a ping, it cannot resolve `www.myapp.com`, but it can resolve `myapp.com`.

Of course, if I try `myapp.cloudapp.net` it works perfectly.

There is still an `A` record in the DNS Manager, should I remove it? What may I be doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: You should probably ask this on ServerFault or SuperUser as it is not really a programming question (Server Fault is SO for these kind of questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this is moved to SuperUser, do you have a hosting account with GoDaddy? The reason I ask is because they don't handle your DNS for you unless you pay for hosting too.

This leaves you with two options

1. [Pay](http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns) for it
2. Get it [free](http://zoneedit.com)

I recommend trying [the free option](http://zoneedit.com) first

Comment: I see now. I've set a forwarding from www.myapp.com to myapp.cloudapp.net instead the CNAME and now it's working. Apparently it can be done, since the forwarding from myapp.com to www.myapp.com was working. Thanks!

Comment: GoDaddy does have a DNS app and does not require hosting.

Comment: @vtortola Hi, Even for me CName is not working, how did you set Forwarding?